# termius local sftp setup on ubuntu

Tags: sftp

I've trouble setting up termius client SFTP connection with the local directory. it shows "Local terminal is not available in a sandbox" and "Install termius from the website to get local terminal". but I already installed the termius app. How can i access the local host file from termius SFTP client.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. This is [the official answer](https://support.termius.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402367330201-SFTP):

> Accessing the local host is currently not possible using Termius
> downloaded from Mac App Store and Snap, unless you access the local
> host as if it was a remote host, i.e. through SSH, which requires a
> locally installed and enabled SSH server. It's not possible because
> Termius in these app stores is sandboxed, meaning it can't access your
> local drive. You can download a non-sandboxed version of the app for
> Mac / Linux from the website.
>
> Termius in Google Play and iOS App Store has limited access to your
> local drive – to the app's directory on iOS and the app's directory
> and certain other directories on Android.